# Excel Simple multiplication not working

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

[Dipiction of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZqDp.png)

I'm Guessing the problem is the double quotes but im not sure how to combat this problem.

The data is pulled from a comma separated file but there is no double quote around anything yet in the Formula Elevator it clearly show's quote's

I'm dumbstruck by this help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA code removing the " could be something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9) = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7) * Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8), """", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Unit$ column is getting identified as text. You can convert text to numbers an it should do the job. The formula will start throwing out numbers the moment this is done.

I usually use method no 4, but there's many ways you can do it.  See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/291047).

Comment: Yes but how can i do this programatically

Comment: Actually I've solved my problem, The vb end of line was being identified as a single " from my data pull. I changed the newline to a custom and its working